# Meteor Subscriptions - Customised Helper Function Not working

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

**When I subscribe to a mongodb collection in the client and publish in the server whilst switch auto-publish off. Do I need to specify each individual find query I am declaring in my helper functions within the publish method? Or is it sufficient to just return Meteor.collection.find() in the Publish statement and that should give access to the entire collection?**

**Lost? Please see below**

In my application I have 2 mongo collections setup. One Called 'Tables' and another called 'Rolls'.

In my client.js file I have two handlebars helper functions:

```
Template.tables.tableList = function(){
    return Tables.find();   
}

Template.tableBox.table = function(tableID){
    return Rolls.find({"Roll.tableName": tableID}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit:10});
}
```

to correspond to my templates:

```
<template name="tables">
    <div class="table-area">
    {{#each tableList}}
      {{> tableBox}}
    {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>


<template name="tableBox">
    <table id="{{name}}" class="table table-condensed">
        <tr class="n{{minBet}}">
            <th>{{name}}</th>
            <th> Min:</th>
            <th>{{minBet}}</th>
            <th>{{cPlayers}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>D2</td>
            <td>D3</td>
            <td>Tot</td>
        </tr>
        {{#each table name}}
          {{> tableRow}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</template>


<template name="tableRow">
        <tr class={{rowColor Roll.dice1 Roll.dice2 Roll.dice3 Roll.total}} "bold">
            <td>{{Roll.dice1}}</td>
            <td>{{Roll.dice2}}</td>
            <td>{{Roll.dice3}}</td>
            <td>{{Roll.total}}</td>
        </tr>
</template>
```

*The first helper function returns all the Tables in the collection. 
The 2nd returns the last 10 Rolls in descending order.*

Using autopublish - everything works fine. My page shows all the tables and within each table the last 10 dicerolls.

When I switch autopublish off and try and setup corresponding subscribe/publish statements. It doesn't work.  Only the Tables are shown - but the data from the Rolls collection is not populating my template.

Corresponding Subscribe and Publish Code:

In client.js:

```
Meteor.subscribe('tables');
Meteor.subscribe('rolls');
```

In server/publications.js:

```
Meteor.publish('tables', function() {
  return Tables.find();
});

Meteor.publish('rolls', function() {
  return Rolls.find();
});
```

**My assumption is that it is to do with my slightly complicated query in my handlebars helper function for the rolls table?  Is it not a simple *subscribe to the whole collection (i.e. publish the return of Rolls.find()*) and then be able to access all mongo query subsets that I define within my client?  Is there something I'm missing here?  Thanks for any help.**

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it is due to Rolls collection not being fully loaded on the client yet at the time you query for it. You can try something like:

```
Template.tables.tableList = function(){
  return Tables.find();   
}

Template.tableBox.table = function(tableID){
  Deps.autorun(function () {
    return Rolls.find({"Roll.tableName": tableID}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit:10});
  });
}
```

The [`Deps.autorun(func)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun) block runs the encapsulated function whenever the reactive dependencies change.